# disabled button gets enabled on toggling between tabs and pages

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to disable a button on certain condition. I tried to use data-ng-class but when I change the tabs or switch between pages the buttons are getting activated intermittently. Would like to understand how can I achieve this feature.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success"  href="" data-ng-click="saveValueSellerBid(false);" data-ng-class="{disabled: currentQuote.acceptPricingSellerDisabled}">
                                    <svg class="icon icon-checkmark"><title>Accept value seller offer</title><use xlink:href="#icon-checkmark"></use></svg>
                                    <strong translate="Accept_Pricing_Seller_Offer"></strong>       
        </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this attribute instead:

```
ng-disabled="currentQuote.acceptPricingSellerDisabled"
```

Comment: It worked first time but when i change page or tab it is activated again

Comment: I am trying to figure out, what could be the possible bug. ideally ng-disabled should work.

Comment: Add {{currentQuote.acceptPricingSellerDisabled}} for debugging so you see the value.

Comment: Value of the expression is true when page loads first but it becomes false when I toggle between tabs.